# GIF pictures on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, animated-gif

I want to add animated pictures (GIF) on my wall like this

```
http://www.facebook.com/tc.turkiy3m.tc?sk=app_4949752878
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it just like someone did on the link you have posted.

Comment: I don't want to share, I want to create a new one, I tried to create I page and put on it GIF image and take its link but didn't animated on Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, Facebook isn't supporting animated GIF images and once posted it'll be flatten.

What you see in the sample you've provided isn't wall but application running in Page Tab, those applications are not part of Facebook and developers are free to do whatever they want unless it not violate platform policies...

***Update:***
Aside of link you provided in question the one you refer in comments indeed profile with animated GIF images in feed stories. This is looks like a bug (probably discovered in the last couple of weeks, I didn't able to find anything like this dated earlier, and I hope it'll be fixed soon. In fact there already was a [bug with animated images a wile ago that should be already fixed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/20827)).

BTW, I filed a bug and waiting to get some response from officials on the subject so things may be clarified...

Comment: Yeah, but in the link above http://www.facebook.com/tc.turkiy3m.tc?sk=app_4949752878 is animated

Comment: @JustMe, yep, but it have nothing to do with wall.

Comment: And this is animated GIF in the Facebook wall http://www.facebook.com/tc.turkiy3m.tc?sk=wall

Comment: And if you can share any in your wall

Comment: @JustMe. Holly @&#^%. This is clearly a bug (probably with OpenGraph meta tags) since the image returned from Facebook server with content type `image/jpeg` which they not! Thanks for pointing. Hope it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: some how they do it https://www.facebook.com/Static.FBMLs/posts/298116696925941

Comment: @Xenon, This is a bug that was discovered couple of weeks ago, have you seen any GIF on Facebook dated before?.. Try to find this documented.

Comment: I reached this topic after discovering this GIF app:https://www.facebook.com/MI.CORAZON.TEAM.ADMIN.PRO?sk=app_203351739677351